# LINQ query Using Entity Framework in C# to get Single Column & Single Row Value Without using Where

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, security, asp.net-mvc-4

LINQ query to get Single Column & Single Row value.

Creating a login module using `SHA512` in `MVC4`. I have two tables as `UserMaster` & `tblSalt`. From `UserMaster` I have retrieved all the fields but in `tblSalt` table there is only one column with one row, therefore can't use `Where` condition. How to access that column?

```
//Retrive Stored HASH Value From Database According To Username (one unique field)  
var userInfo = db.UserMasters.Where(s => s.Username == entity.Username.Trim()).FirstOrDefault();  
var saltVAL = db.tblsalts.Max(s => s.saltvalue.ToString().Trim()).FirstOrDefault();
//Assign HASH Value  
if (userInfo != null)  
{  
    OLDHASHValue = userInfo.Hashpwd;  
    SALT = saltVAL.  ;  
}
```

Expected to access `saltvalue` column from `saltVAL` variable & get initialized to `SALT` variable.

Comment: Just an fyi: Salt (in cryptography) is random data used as additional input to a hashing function, which gets newly generated for each password. So your salt table shouldn't have only 1 entry (except if only 1 password is registered). More on salt in cryptography: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Comment: @MindSwipe I have kept saltvalue common for all users. I would just need to access that column from the table. That how should I do?

Comment: You could just use `db.tblsalts.FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FirstOrDefault()` to grab the first row from your table (or null if the table is empty)

```
var saltVAL = db.tblsalts.FirstOrDefault()
```